# create a forward email rule but send as different user?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, forwarding

I've got 2 email accounts in my outlook 2013 client. I need to forward the emails received by Account2 to a 3rd party. The issue is the forward email rule assumes the Account2 address, but I don't have send as permissions from that account. So forwarding needs to happen via Account1. In the rules menu there doesn't seem to be an option for specifying "send as". What can i do?

Comment: Hi - do you have access to owa for account2..? If yes, then you should be able to create a server based forwarding rule on that one. Be aware though that some organizations do not allow this behavior due to confidentiality and security issues, so better also check with the owner of account2 and the Exchange team/IT Support in your organization,

Comment: I do not. account2 is just a sort if inbox for collecting reports. nothing is sent out from there. I don't think anyone has send permissions